# Why There Are Different Behaviors With Groovy Command Line Arguments?

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy file named `test.groovy` and have a single line of coding in it :

```
println args[0];
```

when I run this program like this `groovy test ants`, output is `ants`.

But when I run the program with the argument `ants(` then I'm getting error like this :

`bash: syntax error near unexpected token (`

1)If I escape the character `(` then I'm getting the output as `ants(`. But why `(` is needed to be escaped?

And when I run the program with the argument `ant's`, then clicking enter would make my terminal look like this :

```
>
>
>
```

2)And I terminate the program only using `ctrl+c`. What actually happens in this case? Why my terminal look like this?

3)After seeing these, what are the rules and condition that are to be followed in Groovy with accordance with Command-line arguments and the same holds for Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bash is parsing those options, not groovy.  Replace `groovy test` with `echo` and you'll get the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape it as ( has a meaning in the bash shell which you are using.

The same goes for '

Try other commands:

```
ls (
```

Or

```
ls '
```

You'll get the same effect

Another option (other than escaping) is to put your arguments inside quote chars like so:

```
groovy test 'ants('
```